# How to parse a .dta file using the row and columns as keys using python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a file that is set up like:

```
    1     2      3        4
A  Yes    word   string   23
B  3     NaN     23       4
C  cx    23      sd       s
```

I am attempting to use python insert the parsed data into an sql database based on the columns and rows. The columns are each a different variable, and as such there is a variable table for each variable. As in:  tbl 1 will include data points 1A, 2A, 3A, and so on. The code I am trying to use is:

```
f= pd.read_stata(myfile)
x = f.columns
for row in f.iterrows():
    for column in x:
        a = 0
        if pd.notnull(row):
            s = str(row[column])
            cur.execute(Insert into tbl{} (sqlcolumn, sqlcolumn2) VALUES (%s, %s).format((x[a]), (s, #))
            a += 1
            conn.commit
```

Modules I am using include Pandas, pg8000, and the python version is 2.7.5. I have little experience in python. The error I get is that the tuple in the line s=str(row[column]) must be an integer, and not a string.

Comment: Your query is not syntactically valid Python.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `row` is a `tuple` which in this case means that `pd.notnull(row)` will always test `True`.